# Repopulate Dropdown when database changes in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Customer table has two fields : FullName And Gender

Lets say , I have dropdown customers. Customers is populated by fetching data from the customer table.

Now Lets I say I have two tabs open in the browser
1)You can perform CRUD functions on Customer table
2)Contains the customers dropdown and some other relevant data.

Performing a Crud operation in tab1 should automatically update the dropdown in the second tab without a refresh page.

How can I achieve this in asp.net mvc or asp.net ?

Like is it possible to bind my dropdown to a table change in asp.net ?

Comment: Typically a use case like this would utilize SignalR (or something similar) as a means of informing any downstream clients (specifically Tab 2 in your case) that they need to refresh themselves.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make use of [Web Sockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_server). This protocol keeps a TCP connection open between the server and the client and changes to the customer table can be sent to the client.

The good news is that Microsoft provides an implementation of Web Socket protocol called [SignalR](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/apps/aspnet/signalr) and that simplifies things a lot.